# Are the blur pictures of black hole a proof of Heisenberg's uncertainity principle?

Tags: black-holes, astronomy, error-analysis

I wonder that are the blur pictures of black holes due to Heisenberg's Uncertainty principle because the velocity of black holes is unpredictable that's why we couldn't take better pictures of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is definitely not due to Heisenberg's Uncertainity Principle. This is because the it only works at the quantum level (and black holes are far from quantum)! The reason pictures of black holes are blurry is a result of their intense gravitiational field, which even light cannot escape from. As a result, we cannot capture an image of the actual black hole, but rather the light near the black hole's event horizon.

To answer your question, the telescopes used to get the image reach a fundamental resolution limit, and this has got absolutely nothing to do with Heisenberg's Uncertainity Principle.

Comment: It's not clear how intense gravitational field will cause blurry image. I'll agree with the second paragraph though